# concurrent update or insert Limit in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a application where we are going to insert thousands of records at the same time in my postgresql database Table, I have explored web but was not able to find right answer of my query.
Please let me know the limit of Update,Insert command on postgresql database table.

If there are any limit then what is the best way to insert,update records if we are updating and inserting thousands of records at the same time in a single table...There will be a deadlock situation if I am not right.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "limit" are you talking about? Inserting or updating thousands of rows at the same time is not a problem. After all that's precisely what relational databases were made for. Of course if different transactions update (and lock) the **same** rows this _could_ lead to a deadlock. The question is to vague and to broad in order to give a concrete answer

Comment: limit means  there is  any  limit  on  concurrent update or insert more than 1000 users at  the same time .

Comment: There is no such physical (or hardcoded) limit. Of course there is a limit on what your hardware can support but that's a different question.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name ok thanks.